# Reformatting strings according to different properties with OO

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented

I had to write a cycle that loops a log file and assigns a given status according to some logic.

I didn't post the whole code but this is the script that bugs me the most... why?

Well, first:

- I thought I was writing  OO... but I guess, I didn't
- Each import from Status is an Enum, it might be wrong, and I auto-assign each Enum to a Row in the first place... Not good, I guess
- I wrote a lot of operations inside each `__init__`tags because each object is an iteration of the one before, with something added to it.

I really don't like the code and I think I could've done a way better job if I had more time (and a bigger brain).

Still... the code works, so... case closed? Even if I need to add some functionalities

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Status import rowType, isComplete

class Row():
    
    def __init__(self, content:str) -> None:
        self.content = content.strip()
        self.type    = rowType.assign(self)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.content

class Rows():
    
    def __init__(self, rows) -> None:
        self.rows = [Row(f'{_}\n') for _ in [_.strip() for _ in rows] if _]
        self.update()

    def __iter__(self):
        return RowsIterator(self.rows)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.rows)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.rows[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx: int, val: Row) -> None:
        self.rows[idx] = val

    def update(self):
        for index, row in enumerate(self.rows):
            # Assegnazione dello stato di completamento
            if row.type == rowType.STX:
                if index+1!=len(self.rows):
                    for subRow in self.rows[index+1:]:
                        if subRow.type == rowType.ETX:
                            row.type =rowType.NULL
                            subRow.type = isComplete.OK
                            break
                        if subRow.type == rowType.STX:
                            row.type = isComplete.KO
                            break
                else:
                    row.type = isComplete.KO
            updateContent = f'[updated={row.type.value}]'
            if row.type != rowType.NULL:
                row.content = row.content+updateContent
        return self.rows


class RowsIterator():

    def __init__(self, rows: Rows) -> None:
        self.idx = 0
        self.row = rows
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> Row:
        self.idx += 1
        try:
            return self.row[self.idx-1]
        except IndexError:
            self.idx = 0
            raise StopIteration


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unit_test = ['Start','Start','DontCareAboutThisString','','\n','Start','DontCareAboutThisEither','Stop']
    for i in Rows(unit_test):
        print(i)
```

#### Update

Added Status

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from enum import Enum

class rowType(Enum):
    NULL = '§NULL§VALUE§'
    STX  = 'Start'
    ETX  = 'Stop'

    def assign(row):
        for type in rowType:
            if type.value in row.content:
                return type
        return rowType.NULL


class isComplete(Enum):
    OK = 'Complete'
    KO = 'NotComplete'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Comment: The logic seems a bit odd in that it won't handle overlapping cases like `['Start 1', 'Start 2', 'Stop 1', 'Stop 2']` or nested cases like `['Start 1', 'Start 2', 'Stop 2', 'Stop 1']`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @RootTwo at the time I found it odd too, and after 2 days, you are right, but the project manager just asked me to write this logic and a lot of other functionalities. They never interviewed our clients, so I'll know if something isn't what they asked for, as always, in production...

Answer (score 3):

> I thought I was writing OO... but I guess, I didn't

This is basically OO, though some aspects of it can be improved.

> Each import from Status is an Enum, it might be wrong, and I auto-assign each Enum to a Row in the first place

Overall, inferring an enum value from a line string is fine. Some aspects of the way you've done this can be improved.

> case closed?

Not quite.

`rowType` should be `RowType` by PEP8.

`assign()` is problematic because it's effectively a static but you haven't annotated it as such. For loose coupling, you should just accept the content string rather than the row object that contains it.

`isComplete` should be something like `Completeness`.

`OK` and `KO` are not good names. `COMPLETE` and `INCOMPLETE` would make more sense.

Don't `if __name__ == '__main__': pass`; since this is a sub-module just delete those lines.

`_` is only to be used for a variable that's write-once, read-never. You need to give those loop iteration variables actual names.

You strip your lines, add a newline, and then strip them again! Strip once, don't add a newline.

You've written `Rows` to pretend to be a sequence. This seems unnecessary, particularly since the `.rows` member is exposed. Delete those boilerplate methods and the entire `RowsIterator` class.

The Italian comment *# Assegnazione dello stato di completamento*, since it's in the code and not localised user content, should be in English - "Assignment of completion status".

The contents of `update()` are better left to a method on `Row` itself.

You have not written a unit test because you `print` rather than `assert`ing. Add asserts.

### Suggested

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Iterable, Sequence


class RowType(Enum):
    NULL = '§NULL§VALUE§'
    STX = 'Start'
    ETX = 'Stop'

    @classmethod
    def assign(cls, content: str) -> 'RowType':
        for type in cls:
            if type.value in content:
                return type
        return cls.NULL


class Completeness(Enum):
    COMPLETE = 'Complete'
    INCOMPLETE = 'NotComplete'


class Row:
    def __init__(self, content: str) -> None:
        self.content = content.strip()
        self.type = RowType.assign(self.content)

    def assign_status(self, tail: Sequence['Row']) -> None:
        if self.type != RowType.STX:
            return

        if tail:
            for sub_row in tail:
                if sub_row.type == RowType.ETX:
                    self.type = RowType.NULL
                    sub_row.type = Completeness.COMPLETE
                    break
                if sub_row.type == RowType.STX:
                    self.type = Completeness.INCOMPLETE
                    break
        else:
            self.type = Completeness.INCOMPLETE

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self.type == RowType.NULL:
            return self.content
        return f'{self.content}[updated={self.type.value}]'


class Rows:
    def __init__(self, row_lines: Iterable[str]) -> None:
        self.rows = [
            Row(content)
            for line in row_lines
            if (content := line.strip())
        ]
        self.update_rows()

    def update_rows(self) -> None:
        for index, row in enumerate(self.rows):
            # Assignment of completion status
            row.assign_status(self.rows[index+1:])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lines = (
        'Start', 'Start', 'DontCareAboutThisString', '',
        '\n', 'Start', 'DontCareAboutThisEither', 'Stop',
    )
    expected = [
        'Start[updated=NotComplete]',
        'Start[updated=NotComplete]',
        'DontCareAboutThisString',
        'Start',
        'DontCareAboutThisEither',
        'Stop[updated=Complete]',
    ]
    assert expected == [
        str(row) for row in Rows(lines).rows
    ]
```

Comment: I'll study your code in order to be better. I often have to write the same code several times in different way before a somewhat good, comprehensible, way of writing code... I also work on different project within time crunches...

About the italian, I axed some stuff (comments and so on) that wasn't needed and changed some variables, I forgot that comment!

I really like your code btw, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to iterate on this and submit a new version in another question.

Answer (score 3):

**The Rows and RowsIterator classes aren't adding much**. If you have a plain
list of Row instances, you already have an object that you can iterate over.
And the Rows class itself does not do very much for you, other than provide a
home for some parsing logic (more on that below).

**The `Row.type` attribute is being abused**. For some Row instances, the
attribute ends up being a RowType instance, which makes sense. But in other
cases, it ends up being a Completeness instance, which makes no sense. It seems
much more natural and straightforward to give Row another attribute:
`is_complete`. [Here and elsewhere, I'm using the renamings suggested in
another review].

**A `Row.assign_status` method should not be mutating other Row instances**. At
least not if you can avoid it. And you can.

**A simpler approach: an ordinary Enum**. Should the code to convert a string
to a RowType reside in Row or RowType? I would put it in Row: under this model,
Row uses RowType and the enum is nothing more than an enum. [If you do end up
putting the logic in RowType, `assign` is a bad name: what is being assigned?
More natural would be something like `from_str`: given a str, return a
RowType.]

```
from enum import Enum

class RowType(Enum):
    START = 'Start'
    STOP = 'Stop'
    NULL = '§NULL§VALUE§'
```

**A simpler approach: an `is_complete` attribute**. If a Row knows whether
it is complete, you can easily create the ultimate strings that you want.
For example:

```
class Row():

    def __init__(self, content, is_complete = False):
        rt_gen = (rt for rt in RowType if rt.value in content)
        self.content = content.strip()
        self.type = next(rt_gen, RowType.NULL)
        self.is_complete = is_complete

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.type == RowType.START:
            suffix = '' if self.is_complete else '[updated=NotComplete]'
        elif self.type == RowType.STOP:
            suffix = '[updated=Complete]' if self.is_complete else '[updated=Stop]'
        else:
            suffix = ''
        return f'{self.content}{suffix}'
```

**A simpler approach: parse the text**. The complexity introduced by your
various classes has sort of cloaked the underlying problem: namely that you
need to parse a log file holistically not only (a) to grab data of interest,
but also (b) to determine when START and STOP log entries are properly paired.
This seems like a simple thing to do in an ordinary function framed as a
parser.

```
def lines_to_rows(lines):
    # Create naive rows that don't yet know whether they are complete.
    stripped_gen = (line.strip() for line in lines)
    rows = [
        Row(line)
        for line in filter(None, stripped_gen)
    ]

    # Traverse the rows in reverse order to discover row mates.
    mates = []
    m = None
    for r in reversed(rows):
        mates.append(m)
        if r.type in (RowType.START, RowType.STOP):
            m = r

    # If we re-reverse and zip them together, we can find the
    # situations where a START is followed by a STOP.
    for r, m in zip(rows, reversed(mates)):
        if m and r.type == RowType.START and m.type == RowType.STOP:
            r.is_complete = True
            m.is_complete = True

    return rows
```